# How do I configure Nexus Sonatype to proxy maven-jgitflow-plugin

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I have configured a proxy in sonatype for the atlassian repo as follows:

```
Remote Storage Location: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/
```

when i try to use the plugin it does not pickup my configuration from pom for the plugin and I see this error:

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jgitflow-plugin:jar:1.0-m5.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jgitflow-plugin:1.0-m5.1: Plugin com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jgitflow-plugin:1.0-m5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jgitflow-plugin:jar:1.0-m5.1 in https://<my local maven server>/content/groups/internal was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of <servername> has elapsed or updates are forced
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the groupId/artifactId are incorrect. the working entry for me is

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-m5.1</version>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: Also is available via [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|jgitflow-maven-plugin)